# Problem with installing Cisco VPN Client on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, vpn, cisco-vpn

When attempting to install Cisco VPN version 4.9.01, I am getting the following error:

```
The driver is blocked due to compatibility issues
Driver: Deterministic Networks
Publisher: Deterministic Networks
Location: Not Available
```

This driver is incompatible with the version of Windows you are upgrading to.  It is likely that the driver is part of another networking software package and will need to be uninstalled before you attempt this upgrade again.

In addition, this also causes me to loose my internet connection until I uninstall VPN.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [**this post**](http://weblogs.asp.net/bhouse/archive/2009/01/15/how-to-successfully-install-cisco-vpn-client-on-windows-7.aspx), which indicates that you need v5.0.4.0300 or newer on Windows 7.  Do you have the option of using a newer version?  [**Cisco's VPN client page**](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/sw/secursw/ps2308/) doesn't yet list support for Windows 7.

Comment: We actually upgraded our PIX to an ASA 5505 which resolved this particular problem.  We were also unable to VPN into any 64 bit machine until after the upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

When installing the Cisco client, you will always temporarily lose your Internet connection. In the event that after the install you still have not regained your connection, use WinSockFix to restore it.

Otherwise, check out the ShrewSoft VPN Client if you need the ability to connect on Windows 7. I've used it on Win 7 Home Premium 64-bit and Win 7 Pro 32-bit with no issues. I was even able to import my .pcf files.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a 64 bit version of Windows 7.  If this is the case you MUST use the Cisco Anyconnect VPN client (which is SSL only I am afraid - so you are going to have to cough up for those expensive SSL licences for your ASAs)...

Comment: But then again: SSL is the best thing since sliced bread when connecting from public networks :)